# Iterating through Arraylist with extended classes

Tags: java, class, iteration

I have been wondering about a function in Java, which I hope exists. I want to iterate through an Arraylist (say of class A), which contains objects of class B and C which both extend A. The idea, I only want to iterate through (for example) the objects of the B class in the ArrayList.

How is this possible, like the short example in the code below, and without the long one?

The main class:

```
     import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test ();
    }

    Test() {
        ArrayList<A> a = new ArrayList<A> ();
        a.add (new B ());
        a.add (new C ());
        a.add (new C ());
        a.add (new B ());
        a.add (new C ());
        for (A aObject : a) { // this works, I want it shorter
            if (aObject instanceof B) {
                B b = (B) aObject;
                System.out.println (b.hi);
            }
        }
        for (B b : a) // like this?
            System.out.println (b.hi);
    }
}
```

A:

```
public class A {

}
```

B:

```
public class B extends A {
    String hi = "hi";
}
```

C:

```
public class C extends A {

}
```

EDIT: Because so many people answer this: I know of the use of instanceof. I want a faster way to loop through all the objects in the array, of which the class is B.

Comment: You have to iterate through all the list and for every object of the list to check if it is of the class you want. You may want to look in the keywork "instance of" as already stated in an answer below... but i am afraid that the code will be similar to the one you have (but the instance of approach is better/ cleaner)

Comment: The question before you edited it wasn't clear as to what you were asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a reusable Filter class for it, similar to `FileFilter`.  (See korifey's answer for the use of guava.)  Other than that, no, there isn't any existing functionality to do it.  Additionally, any existing functionality would have to do exactly what you're doing anyway, as the `List` types don't have any way of knowing where the different classes of objects are in the list.  (It would have to iterate over them as well to find them.)

If you require a high-performance solution around this, you could consider storing separate lists for your separate instances - either in replacement of or in addition to your current list.  You could even wrap this up in a composite class that would offer both functionalities (all instances and instances by class) through a common API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was just curious, no need for high performance, but maybe I'll once need it. Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/index.html)

Like this:

```
for (B b: Iterables.filter(a, B.class)) {
 System.out.println (b.hi);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as the OP: the filter accepts C instances, whereas the OP only accepts B instances which are not C. The OP could use a reusable Predicate, though.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. If C extended B, and if the OP had kept its original code where he compared classes rather than using instanceof, then there would be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with JRSofty.

```
for (A aObject : a) {
    if (aObject instanceof B) { // <-- This is as short I can make it
        B b = (B) aObject;
        System.out.println (b.hi);
    }
}
```

Comment: I showed that example already, without the instanceof, but the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simpler loop like this:

```
for (A aObject : a)
    if (aObject instanceof B)
        System.out.println(((B) aObject).hi);
```

It's a better idea using the `instanceof` operator. But for filtering-out the instances of the list which are not of type `B`, you'd need to integrate an additional collections library, since that operation is not supported directly by the standard Collections API. Maybe [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) have support for the kind of filtering operation you want to do, I haven't checked yet.